# Expected Token Error for setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

What am I doing wrong here?

```
<script>setTimeout($("#fsForm1585007").hide();,8000);</script>
```

Sorry, I'm very new to JS. Thanks!

Comment: try jsLint or something to validate. http://www.jslint.com/ You'll see : setTimeout($("#fsForm1585007").hide(), 8000);  an extra semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

The error is due to the semicolon, however, this still wont' do what you want.  You are hiding the element immediately and then passing the result of `hide` into `setTimeout`.  YOu want to instead do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#fsForm1585007").hide();
},8000);
```

In this way, you are passing a function, which, when invoked will hide your element.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got the timer working, sadly I was forced to scrap the whole script to due other limitation. But I really appreciate the help/learning experience!

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout correct syntax is:

```
setTimeout(function ()
{
    alert("hello!");
}, 1000);
```

The "function ()" is a anonymous function parameter of setTimeout(), and "1000" represent the milliseconds to execute the inner code.

Anyway, you can call setTimeout by a function name as string, like this:

```
setTimeout("YourNewFunction", 1000);

function YourNewFunction()
{
    alert("hello!");
}
```

Important to say your code are using jQuery, you need import jquery script on your page.

[Download or use from CDN](http://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! I got the timer working, sadly I was forced to scrap the whole script to due other limitation. But I really appreciate the help/learning experience!